# Trigger the Job from Shell in Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, curl

I am receiving the following error while trying to trigger the Job from Shell using CURL Command

```
curl -X POST --user Myname@example.com:<APITOKEN> "https://example.com/job/Testing/build?token=TOKEN_NAME"
```

Error Received

```
Authentication required
 <!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
```

and We are using Google Okta authentication for this.

Kindly suggest the way to trigger the Job from Shell.

TIA

Comment: Does the user **Myname@example.com** has correct permission to delete ?

Comment: Yes...it has admin privileges ...